# MathJax rendering issue while looking at someone's profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, profile-page

I have encountered the following issue looking at my [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/515527/zacky?tab=profile), see it in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5kM.jpg).

This also happens if I change the browser or log off from my account or even if I check from my phone, and it also appears while looking at other users profile.

It might be related to my previous [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29612/515527), although there I was using my smartphone.

Is there something that I can/should do in order to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Martin  doesn't imgur give a permanent link? (What else is to be used?) Also do you see the same issue if you look at my profile, or it only appears to me?

Comment: The pictures in the links with the format `https://imgur.com/...` might be deleted after some time. If you upload it through editor, the link to the picture will have the format `https://i.stack.imgur.com` and should (in theory) last indefinitely. A bit more on this: [Permanent Picture Uploads](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4205) and [Broken imgur-links](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483).

Comment: Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98, Windows 10 Pro. Also on Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0.

Comment: I experienced something similar on the moderators tools page (Chromium 72.0.3626.81 on Arch Linux), as well as other various user profiles.

Comment: We upgraded to MathJax 2.7.5 at the end of last week, and it looks like something's off there compared to 2.7.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

As I mentioned in the comments, this was a side-effect of upgrading to MathJax 2.7.5. The core of the issue is [described in detail over on GitHub](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2078).

Many thanks to [Davide Cervone](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7798/davide-cervone) for pointing me in the right direction and suggesting a fix. It's deployed in production now. Please let me know if you see any other oddities.

Comment: Yes, 2.5 years later we are seeing oddities again, so if you are still developing for SE please take a look at [this issue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34112/164025), which looks very similar to the one described on this page. Thank you.