# MathJax formatting on mobile site.

Tags: bug, mathjax, mobile-web

I've noticed lately that MathJax has been paragraphing its output excessively sometimes on the mobile site. I don't know how to describe it, so here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please help :)

Comment: Maybe related https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29728/mathjax-rendering-issue-while-looking-at-someones-profile