# MathJax "jumbled up" in the activity tab of a user

Tags: bug, mathjax, profile-page

I have noticed questions with long MathJax expression in the title get "jumbled up" when I look at the activity tab of some user - in the part listing the most recent questions and answers. (Maybe there are also some other factors in play.)

For example, you can look at the activity tab of the asker (or one of the answerers) of the question: [Find the tangent and normal lines to the curve $\gamma(t)=(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t), 2\sin(t)-\sin(2t))$ at $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895158#3117397) When I check profile of [one of the answerers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/610697/kumar-nilesh?tab=summary), I see this:

[image: screenshot]

[Xander Henderson noticed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51602766#51602766) that the way the title is displayed changes a bit after CMD+click (Ctrl+Right click).

[image: screenshot 2]

I do not expect this to be browser-dependent, but I'll include the information that I am using Google Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.132).

I have seen that there is an older bug report related to MathJax in user profiles: [MathJax rendering issue while looking at someone's profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29728). However, that post concerns another part of the profile page (another tab).

<sup>I will add that I did not intend to single out this specific user/specific post. It simply happened to be the place where I noticed this bug.</sup>

Comment: I had this bug for quite some time. I just felt lazy reporting it. I use Chromium, but I can confirm it doesn't happen on Firefox. Might be a webkit issue.

Comment: Also, neither Firefox nor Chrome on Android exhibit this bug. So might also be specific to desktop. Also, I have this both in my personal computer and in my office (both Chromium, both Linux, but different versions).

Comment: Similar bug report on MathOverflow Meta: [Garbled MathJax in a link to a question with MathJax in the title](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4340).

Comment: I can confirm the bug in Chrome and in my case it is happening since today, it wasn't there before. Also it seems to do only with HTML-CSS math renderer.

Comment: I had this bug before (approximately 2 months ago, in Chrome) it was there for some days and then it disappeared by itself. Note that I saw the bug on the hot network questions and not in Math.stack links like you did see.

Comment: I'm on a 77 beta chrome mobile browser so apparently can't see it.