# The lines in my personal page are mixed up

Tags: bug, mathjax, profile-page

I encounter this bug when visiting my personal [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/368425/le-anh-dung?tab=summary). That means the lines are mixed up.

I use **Google Chrome** Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit).

> [image]

Has somebody encountered this bug as I have?

Comment: This seems to be the same bug as [MathJax “jumbled up” in the activity tab of a user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30644) (and [Garbled MathJax in a link to a question with MathJax in the title](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4340) on MathOverflow Meta).

Comment: Thank you @MartinSleziak! That's it.

Comment: "full.en.js?v=c549c88b4f68:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response " in the errors for your page.